# WSO2 WS based Greg v 4.5.2 mounting with ESB v 4.5.1

Tags: wso2, wso2-governance-registry, wso2-esb

Earlier we were using Governance Registy mounted in our  ESB with Web service mounting option and it was working perfectly fine. But after migrating to Greg v4.5.2 and ESB v4.5.1,  this has stopped working and have made us running in to deep problem as all of our services are not getting deployed due to mounting not working properly.

I have followed the instructions given in the link  http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/Governance453/Remote+Instance+and+Mount+Configuration+Details
We have opted for third option which is WebService-Based Remote Instance Configuration

But after doing what has been mentioned and starting the ESB server, it is giving enormous errors regarding various transports not starting up correctly and the services which were using wsdls and schemas stored in Greg, are not starting, complaining about resource stream coming as null.

I will really appreciate if someone can suggest the way to proceed forward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Webservice(WS-mount) based mount issue which is mentioned here is a bug[1].
And we will be able to apply the fix for next Governance Registry release(4.6.0).

[1]https://wso2.org/jira/browse/REGISTRY-1607

Thanks & Regards,
Ajith

Answer (score 0):

Can you please mention the early versions of G-Reg and ESB ?

However, If you are going to migrate from G-Reg 4.1.1 to G-Reg 4.5.2,

**i) First you need to migrate your G-Reg database.**

**ii) Then you need to migrate the configurations.**

Thanks

Ajith

Comment: we were using Greg 4.1.1 and ESB 4.0.3

Comment: We have setup new Greg 4.5.2 with fresh schema and configuration. Afterwards imported all our wsdls and schemas in to the new one.